(MacKay) How can regularization constants can be optimized on-line in a tractable way?
According to MacKay in his book Information Theory, Inference, and Learning Algorithms, Chapter 44, "Supervised Learning in Multilayer Networks" (page 531), he claims that an advantage of Bayesian optimization of model control parameters (and in particular for neural networks, such as weight decay constants) is the following:

"Regularization constants can be optimized on-line, i.e.,
simultaneously with the optimization of ordinary model
parameters...The gradient of the evidence with respect to the control
parameters can be evaluated, making it possible to simultaneously
optimize a large number of control parameters."

However, I fail to see how the control parameters can be optimized in a tractable way. For example, say we are dealing with a feedforward neural network with a weight decay penalty. Let $\mathcal{D}$ be the data, and $\mathcal{H}_\lambda$ is hypothesis that the prior for your model weights is a multivariate Gaussian with constant variance $\lambda^2$ (here, $\lambda$ is the "control parameter / regularization constant" MacKay speaks of). Then via Bayesian argument, we must choose $\lambda$ such that
$$
\begin{align*}
\lambda^* &= \arg \max_{\lambda} \mathbb{P}[\mathcal{D} | \mathcal{H}_{\lambda}] \\
&= \arg \max_\lambda \int_{\mathbb{R}^{d_w}}\mathbb{P}[\mathcal{D} | w, \mathcal{H}_{\lambda}] \mathbb{P}[w|\mathcal{H}_\lambda] dw
\end{align*}
$$
where $w\in \mathbb{R}^{d_w}$ is the vector of $d_w$ weights in our neural network.
If I am interpreting MacKay correctly, it seems like he's saying that the gradient of the integral w.r.t. $\lambda$ can be easily computed, but I don't understand why this is the case. If I understand correctly, if $E(\lambda) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^{d_w}}\mathbb{P}[\mathcal{D} | w, \mathcal{H}_{\lambda}] \mathbb{P}[w|\mathcal{H}_\lambda] dw$, then
$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{d\lambda} E(\lambda) &= \int_{\mathbb{R}^{d_w}}\mathbb{P}[\mathcal{D} | w, \mathcal{H}_{\lambda}] \frac{d}{d\lambda} \mathbb{P}[w|\mathcal{H}_\lambda] dw \\ 
\end{align*}
$$
Although the gradient inside the integral is easy to compute, the integral itself feels pretty difficult to compute.
In light of this - what did MacKay mean when he writes "the gradient of the evidence with respect to the control parameters can be evaluated"?
